# Accessing global vars from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, button

This code works only works after refreshing page and 'click' becouse vars are defined outside the function. How to make it work live?

```js
var product1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var product2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var product1mult = product1.value * 200;
var product2mult = product2.value * 100;

  $('.success').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').html(product1mult + product2mult)
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1"></input>
     
<input type="text" id="num1"></input>

<a href="#" class="button success">Ukupno sa zastitom</a>
        <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: You're sure the issue isn't just that your using the same ID twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ids must be unique. You had two ids titled `#num1`. Also input tags are self-closing, so there is no need for `</input>`. It should look more like this.

Also, instead of defining two variables for each product, you can simplify it to just one.

Third, you are mixing JavaScript with jQuery. It's a best practice to stick with one. Here is a jQuery solution.

```js
$('.success').on('click', function() {
  var product1 = $("#num1").val() * 100;
  var product2 = $("#num2").val() * 100;
  $('#result').html(product1 + product2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num1" />
<input type="text" id="num2" />

<a href="#" class="button success">Ukupno sa zastitom</a>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: I just made bad c/p, ids are ok. Problem was in my gruntfile: babel not allowed me to define vars inside function. I difened two variables becouse i want to use first one later on. I solve it now. But thanks anyway.